# Extract specific plots from a matrix of plots

Tags: r

I have the timeseries object below and I create a matrix of acf plots. How could I extract only one of all these? Lets say `DAX&CAC`

```
tseu<-ts(EuStockMarkets)

acfs<-acf(tseu)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is stored in the `acfs` object that you created.  You can get the plot that you want using:

```
plot(acfs$acf[,1,3], type="h", ylim=0:1, ylab="", xlab="Lag",
    main=paste(acfs$snames[1], "&", acfs$snames[3]))
```

[image: AutoCorrelation Plot]